# How do I get only two constraints for this Lagrangian?

Tags: self-learning, lagrange-multiplier

In [a paper I'm reading](https://philpapers.org/rec/YANPSW), they minimize a function $g(\alpha)$ subject to something like:

$a(\alpha)=b(\alpha)=c$ $\quad$ (Eq. 6 in the paper)

and

$d(\alpha)=e(\alpha)=f$ $\quad$ (Eq. 7 in the paper)

They skip the details of the minimization, but they do say they used Lagrange multipliers and give a closed form expression for the minimizer as $\alpha(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$.

My question is, **how can I reduce the constraints above to only two equations, so the minimizer will end up being a function of only two lambdas?**

I thought about:

$a(\alpha) - 2b(\alpha) +c = 0$

and

$d(\alpha) - 2e(\alpha) +f = 0$

but I realize these don't necessarily imply the original constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way: \begin{align*}
(a(\alpha) - c)^2 + (b(\alpha) - c)^2 = 0  &\text{ and}  \\
(d(\alpha) - f)^2 + (e(\alpha) - f)^2 = 0  &\text{.} 
\end{align*}

This works if everything in sight is a real number or a real valued function.  It does not work in the complex setting.